# Is the degree of a mapping on a ball equal to its degree on the ball's boundary?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Each continuous mapping between compact oriented manifolds of the same dimension has a [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping), which is an integer number.

Let $f$ be a continuous mapping from the $n$-dimensional ball $\mathbb{B}^n$ to itself. Suppose $f$ maps the boundary of $\mathbb{B}^n$ to itself. So we can define a mapping $g$, which is the restriction of $f$ to the $(n-1)$-dimensional boundary of $\mathbb{B}^n$.

Is there any relation between the degree of $f$ (as an $n$-dimensional mapping) and the degree of $g$ (as an $(n-1)$-dimensional mapping)?

In particular, is it true that $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$?

Comment: How do you define the degree of a manifold with boundary?

Comment: @ThomasRot Good question. Here is an attempt. Let $\mathbb{B}'^n$ be a mirror-image of $\mathbb{B}^n$, and let $f': \mathbb{B}'^n\to \mathbb{B}'^n$ be the corresponding mirror-image of $f:\mathbb{B}^n\to \mathbb{B}^n$. If we glue $\mathbb{B}^n$ and $\mathbb{B}'^n$ at their boundary, we get the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$. Since $f$ maps the boundary to the boundary, we now have a continuous mapping of $\mathbb{S}^n$ to $\mathbb{S}^n$. So let's define $\deg(f)$ as the degree of that mapping.

Comment: So in the one-dimensional case, $f$ is a function from the interval 
$[-1,1]$ to itself. There are two cases: if $f(-1)=f(1)$ then the degree of the glued function on $S^1$ is 0, otherwise its degree is 1 or -1.